# Javascript library not functioning when referenced from alternative server

Tags: javascript, html, ssl-certificate

I have a copy of bubbles.js uploaded to my rental server and have made only one tiny, tiny change which should still function, yet when I run from https://www.codecademy.com/ShakyaJR/codebits/4YKBRb/ calling the version at http://www.orderofthemouse.co.uk/js/bubbles.js the code does not function at all. However, the version on the Amazon CDN seems to work fine.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/alphabet.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.orderofthemouse.co.uk/js/bubbles.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, the default HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/alphabet.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/bubbles.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

seems to work without issue.

For convenience, the relevant Javascript is:

```
function Vector(x, y, z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;

    this.set = function (x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    };
}

function PointCollection() {
    this.mousePos = new Vector(0, 0);
    this.pointCollectionX = 0;
    this.pointCollectionY = 0;
    this.points = [];

    this.update = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
            var point = this.points[i];

            var dx = this.mousePos.x - point.curPos.x;
            var dy = this.mousePos.y - point.curPos.y;
            var dd = (dx * dx) + (dy * dy);
            var d = Math.sqrt(dd);

            point.targetPos.x = d < 150 ? point.curPos.x - dx : point.originalPos.x;
            point.targetPos.y = d < 150 ? point.curPos.y - dy : point.originalPos.y;

            point.update();
        }
    };

    this.shake = function () {
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) - 2;

        for (var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
            var point = this.points[i];
            var dx = this.mousePos.x - point.curPos.x;
            var dy = this.mousePos.y - point.curPos.y;
            var dd = (dx * dx) + (dy * dy);
            var d = Math.sqrt(dd);
            if (d < 50) {
                this.pointCollectionX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) - 2;
                this.pointCollectionY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) - 2;
            }
            point.draw(bubbleShape, this.pointCollectionX, this.pointCollectionY);
        }
    };

    this.draw = function (bubbleShape, reset) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
            var point = this.points[i];

            if (point === null)
                continue;

            if (window.reset) {
                this.pointCollectionX = 0;
                this.pointCollectionY = 0;
                this.mousePos = new Vector(0, 0);
            }

            point.draw(bubbleShape, this.pointCollectionX, this.pointCollectionY, reset);
        }
    };

    this.reset = function (bubbleShape) {};
}

function Point(x, y, z, size, color) {
    this.curPos = new Vector(x, y, z);
    this.color = color;

    this.friction = document.Friction;
    this.rotationForce = document.rotationForce;
    this.springStrength = 0.1;

    this.originalPos = new Vector(x, y, z);
    this.radius = size;
    this.size = size;
    this.targetPos = new Vector(x, y, z);
    this.velocity = new Vector(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    this.update = function () {
        var dx = this.targetPos.x - this.curPos.x;
        var dy = this.targetPos.y - this.curPos.y;
        // Orthogonal vector is [-dy,dx]
        var ax = dx * this.springStrength - this.rotationForce * dy;
        var ay = dy * this.springStrength + this.rotationForce * dx;

        this.velocity.x += ax;
        this.velocity.x *= this.friction;
        this.curPos.x += this.velocity.x;

        this.velocity.y += ay;
        this.velocity.y *= this.friction;
        this.curPos.y += this.velocity.y;

        var dox = this.originalPos.x - this.curPos.x;
        var doy = this.originalPos.y - this.curPos.y;
        var dd = (dox * dox) + (doy * doy);
        var d = Math.sqrt(dd);

        this.targetPos.z = d / 100 + 1;
        var dz = this.targetPos.z - this.curPos.z;
        var az = dz * this.springStrength;
        this.velocity.z += az;
        this.velocity.z *= this.friction;
        this.curPos.z += this.velocity.z;

        this.radius = this.size * this.curPos.z;
        if (this.radius < 1) this.radius = 1;
    };

    this.draw = function (bubbleShape, dx, dy) {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        if (bubbleShape == "square") {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillRect(this.curPos.x + dx, this.curPos.y + dy, this.radius * 1.5, this.radius * 1.5);
        } else {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(this.curPos.x + dx, this.curPos.y + dy, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            ctx.fill();
        }
    };
}

function makeColor(hslList, fade) {
    var hue = hslList[0] /*- 17.0 * fade / 1000.0*/ ;
    var sat = hslList[1] /*+ 81.0 * fade / 1000.0*/ ;
    var lgt = hslList[2] /*+ 58.0 * fade / 1000.0*/ ;
    return "hsl(" + hue + "," + sat + "%," + lgt + "%)";
}

function phraseToHex(phrase) {
    var hexphrase = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
        hexphrase += phrase.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
    }
    return hexphrase;
}

function initEventListeners() {
    $(window).bind('resize', updateCanvasDimensions).bind('mousemove', onMove);

    canvas.ontouchmove = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        onTouchMove(e);
    };

    canvas.ontouchstart = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    };
}

function updateCanvasDimensions() {
    canvas.attr({
        height: 500,
        width: 1000
    });
    canvasWidth = canvas.width();
    canvasHeight = canvas.height();
    draw();
}

function onMove(e) {
    if (pointCollection) {
        pointCollection.mousePos.set(e.pageX - canvas.offset().left, e.pageY - canvas.offset().top);
    }
}

function onTouchMove(e) {
    if (pointCollection) {
        pointCollection.mousePos.set(e.targetTouches[0].pageX - canvas.offset().left, e.targetTouches[0].pageY - canvas.offset().top);
    }
}

function bounceName() {
    shake();
    setTimeout(bounceName, 30);
}

function bounceBubbles() {
    draw();
    update();
    setTimeout(bounceBubbles, 30);
}

function draw(reset) {
    var tmpCanvas = canvas.get(0);

    if (tmpCanvas.getContext === null) {
        return;
    }

    ctx = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    bubbleShape = typeof bubbleShape !== 'undefined' ? bubbleShape : "circle";

    if (pointCollection) {
        pointCollection.draw(bubbleShape, reset);
    }
}

function shake() {
    var tmpCanvas = canvas.get(0);

    if (tmpCanvas.getContext === null) {
        return;
    }

    ctx = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    bubbleShape = typeof bubbleShape !== 'undefined' ? bubbleShape : "circle";

    if (pointCollection) {
        pointCollection.shake(bubbleShape);
    }
}

function update() {
    if (pointCollection)
        pointCollection.update();
}

function drawName(name, letterColors) {
    updateCanvasDimensions();
    var g = [];
    var offset = 0;

    function addLetter(cc_hex, ix, letterCols) {
        if (typeof letterCols !== 'undefined') {
            if (Object.prototype.toString.call(letterCols) === '[object Array]' && Object.prototype.toString.call(letterCols[0]) === '[object Array]') {
                letterColors = letterCols;
            }
            if (Object.prototype.toString.call(letterCols) === '[object Array]' && typeof letterCols[0] === "number") {
                letterColors = [letterCols];
            }
        } else {
            // if undefined set black
            letterColors = [[0, 0, 27]];
        }

        if (document.alphabet.hasOwnProperty(cc_hex)) {
            var chr_data = document.alphabet[cc_hex].P;
            var bc = letterColors[ix % letterColors.length];

            for (var i = 0; i < chr_data.length; ++i) {
                point = chr_data[i];

                g.push(new Point(point[0] + offset,
                    point[1],
                    0.0,
                    point[2],
                    makeColor(bc, point[3])));
            }
            offset += document.alphabet[cc_hex].W;
        }
    }

    var hexphrase = phraseToHex(name);

    var col_ix = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < hexphrase.length; i += 2) {
        var cc_hex = "A" + hexphrase.charAt(i) + hexphrase.charAt(i + 1);
        if (cc_hex != "A20") {
            col_ix++;
        }
        addLetter(cc_hex, col_ix, letterColors);
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < g.length; j++) {
        g[j].curPos.x = (canvasWidth / 2 - offset / 2) + g[j].curPos.x;
        g[j].curPos.y = (canvasHeight / 2 - 105) + g[j].curPos.y;
        g[j].originalPos.x = (canvasWidth / 2 - offset / 2) + g[j].originalPos.x;
        g[j].originalPos.y = (canvasHeight / 2 - 105) + g[j].originalPos.y;
    }

    pointCollection = new PointCollection();
    pointCollection.points = g;
    initEventListeners();
}

window.reset = false;

$(window).mouseleave(function () {
    window.reset = true;
});

$(window).mouseenter(function () {
    window.reset = false;
});

var canvas = $("#myCanvas");
var canvasHeight;
var canvasWidth;
var ctx;
var pointCollection;

document.rotationForce = 0.0;
document.Friction = 0.85;

var white = [0, 0, 100];
var black = [0, 0, 27];
var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];

setTimeout(updateCanvasDimensions, 30);
```

A *cod_ae_cademy pro* team member said the problem might be the tiny difference in the JS or something to do with SSL certificates might be plausible too.

The only Javascript line changed is:

```
this.pointCollectionX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) - 2;
```

which I changed from the original bubbles.js line:

```
this.pointCollectionX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) - 2;
```

Comment: this line `<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` should be `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`. You miss the `http:` at the beginning of the url. Hence you are not loading jquery

Comment: Hmmmm, I didn't change the line at all, so it would be interesting to note if that had caused the problem, though I suppose it might be related, particularly as the environment was/is a simulated one and not exactly a standard browser, and probably wasn't intended to deal with the sort of things being requested of it by the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly mine but just so people can clearly see for future learning and reference, I have subsequently received this answer from a member of the *cod_ae_cademy pro* team named Elise (:~)):

**"in this case it seems like [the cod*ae*cademy engineers] have a security setting to require that script [be called in directly from cod*ae*cademy]"**

I didn't pry further into why that might be as it seemed inappropriate to ask too many questions about a major site's security processes unless I had an important reason to do so, and all I really wanted to do was to make my name animate in bubbles which moved at different speeds from the default setting.

Edit: Though I did suggest SSL might be the cause in the initial conversation, so I suppose it is sort of my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't got through all the js code. but usually I would have stored the main.js in a subfolder named js. Hence, are you sure, that the url of the main.js file is correct?

Comment: It should be correct as it was copy and pasted from a seemingly working version, unless the simulated Javascripting environment functions differently from an ordinary browser, which it seems like it may.